# Dayjs format with timezone abbreviation i.e. 'z' like in moment.js

Tags: momentjs, date-formatting, dayjs

Trying to migrate from *Moment.js* to *Dayjs* but the only thing I can't get working is the `Timezone` abbreviation.

```
dayjs('2020-07-06T14:30:00.000-04:00').tz(dayjs.tz.guess()).format('Do MMM YYYY [at] HH:MMa z')
```

Calling the above I would expect `6th Jul 2020 at 08:07am EDT` but currently I am just getting `z` where `EDT` is.

I have added the `utc` and `timezone` plugins and can't see any other plugins needed to make this work, I notice on *Dayjs* format docs that `z` isn't listed but searching the web, I see a lot of folks saying the solution is `format('', {timeZone})` but the `format` doesn't take a second argument??

Looks like it was added to `tz-plugin`: https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/pull/325/files#diff-cad460a5e46a2a48c59e95356c683820R195

Here's a code sandbox with an example of the issue:
https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-knuth-r58gz

**--- Edit**

Looks like support for `tz` abbr was removed :(
https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/pull/448/commits/e64c03cea79c579bcd3c4caf235b4724e56614d4

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `z` formatting option is added in `1.9.0` version of *[dayjs](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/pull/1069)*: https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/pull/1069

Update the newest version and set up the plugins correctly, which should work. Example below:

```
var dayjs = require("dayjs")
var utc = require("dayjs/plugin/utc")
var timezone = require("dayjs/plugin/timezone")
var advanced = requires("dayjs/plugin/advancedFormat")

dayjs.extend(timezone)
dayjs.extend(utc)
dayjs.extend(advanced)
dayjs().tz('Europe/Paris').format('DD/MM/YYYY z')
```

Comment: Oh nice they added support but opted to remove TZ name due to issues with confusion abbr. Using UTC everywhere now

Comment: Been looking for this for hours! Thanks for the simple solution - had everything in there except the `dayjs.extend(advanced)` --> no mention of that in the docs, so thanks!

Comment: When I do this I get '08/06/2023 GMT+2'. How do I get the three letter abbreviation instead of the GMT+n format?

Comment: @JimmyTheCode exactly i am facing same problem. have you figured out the solution ?

Comment: Hi @Bilal, I managed to convince our product team that we should stick to "GMT+1", instead of BST. The reason that dayjs has dropped the three letter abbreviation, is because it's known to cause confusion. For example, BST can mean "British Standard Time" in the UK, but in another locale it might mean "Bahraini Standard Time". There was a good, comprehensive StackOverflow answer on this, but I can't find it right now.

Comment: Hi @JimmyTheCode thanks for letting me know.. if you found that question please post here so other can also get benifit

Answer (score 1):

found this thread https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/issues/1713 there are some workaround if you are interested, the one I might end up using is this

```
new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-AU', {
                            timeZone: 'Australia/Perth',
                            timeZoneName: 'short',
                          })
                            .format(Date.now()).split(' ')[1]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was the pointer I needed.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to above answer, to get the timezone name, pass tripple `zzz` it will return full timezone name

```
dayjs().tz("Europe/Paris").format("DD/MM/YYYY zzz"); // 14/12/2023 Central European Standard Time
```